# How do you call $\succsim$?

Tags: notation, economics

actually, I study economics, not math.

As some of you may know, there is a sign for comparing goods: $\succsim$. My professor read $x\succsim y$ like "x is at least as good as y". I asked her if there is a name for it, but she has no idea.

What I mean by name is something like equality sign for =, or tilda for ~ etc.

Answer (score 5):

The symbol and others similar to it represent preference relations. The particular symbol that you are referencing I believe would be called "succeeds or equivalent to". Here is a [table](http://www.oeconomist.com/blogs/daniel/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/pref_symbols.pdf) that includes a list of symbols that are used to describe preference relations and their names (amongst other information).

Comment: Thank you. I hoped there is kind of shorter name for $\succsim$.

Answer (score 1):

I am more used to call it just "$x$ is (weakly) preferred to $y$," which is usually what it means in economics. I am not sure if this is standard though.

I think what @GAM suggests is more standard in mathematics, since a preference relationship is essentially a (quasi-) order.

Comment: I agree that the preference relation represented by that symbol is weak preference. I assumed that Maxslon was asking about the name of the symbol itself based on the tilde example.

Comment: @GAM Thank you for the clarification. In that case, I would just read it as "preference (relation)" in economics. Again, I don't know if there's a standard.